# NOT NULL constraint failed: app_User.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Iam trying to build a website that contains 2 types of users, so I need to make 2 profiles out of the abstractuser model, the problem is when I'm trying to post the data into the database through forms this error occurs:"NOT NULL constraint failed: app_shahadati_user.user_id". I tried multiple solutions but all of them saves the user at the User's model but I want to save it at the Shahadati_user model.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Shahadati_user(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_nID=models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField()
    password_validation = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','email']

    def clean_password_validation(self):
        pwd1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        pwd2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_validation')
        if pwd1 and pwd2 and pwd1 != pwd2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return pwd2

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
class ShahadatiUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shahadati_user
        fields =['user_nID']
```

views.py

```
def user_reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_ShU = ShahadatiUserForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form_ShU.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form_ShU.save()
      
        else:
            pass
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {})
```

this is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: app_shahadati_user.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\university\graduationProject\Shahadati\app\views.py", line 30, in user_reg
    form_ShU.save()
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 548, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 831, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 882, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1025, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1066, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1790, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1657, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\dandy\miniconda3\envs\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /user_reg/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_shahadati_user.user_id
```

Comment: Can you please paste in the full traceback of the error?

Comment: I did know .. please help :')

Comment: user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error comes from your `user_reg` view, where you are trying to process two forms with the same `request.POST` and `request.FILES` data; this will almost certainly cause issues.

My **strong** suggestion when working on a custom user model in Django is to avoid the `AbstractUser` and `one-to-one` paradigm that you have adopted, and instead use an `AbstractBaseUser` model with all user information contained within it. This would mean you don't need two separate ModelForms for a single view, and you instead have a single form that maps nicely to your view and model.

Then you essentially have a single user model (`CustomUser`) but with two 'types' of user: those for whom `is_shahadati` returns `True` with a shahadati_nID, and those for whom `is_shahadati` returns `False` without a shahadati_nID. This is much more extensible and flexible, with fewer potential points of failure.

Code below:

**models.py**

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=250,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='email address'
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='superuser')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='staff')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='active')

    # Add as many 'optional' fields as you like:
    address = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, default="")
    zip_code = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, default="")
    # Etc.

    shahadati_nID = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        unique=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def is_shahadati(self):
        if self.shahadati_nID > 0:
            return True
        return False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**forms.py**

```py
class CustomUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_validation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'first_name','last_name',
            'email', 'shahadati_nID',
        ]

    def clean_password_validation(self):
        pwd1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        pwd2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_validation')
        if pwd1 and pwd2 and pwd1 != pwd2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return pwd2

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def user_reg(request):
    form = CustomUserCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {'form': form})
```

This should hopefully fix your issue, and provide a more robust implementation for the user model at the same time.

---

UPDATE:

If you need to treat the two types of users distinctly at point of registration, then I recommend having two separate forms and two separate views (with separate registration templates) as below:

**forms.py**

```py
class NormalUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_validation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'first_name','last_name',
            'email', 'address', 'zip_code',
            # Etc., see additional fields in model declaration
        ]

    def clean_password_validation(self):
        pwd1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        pwd2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_validation')
        if pwd1 and pwd2 and pwd1 != pwd2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return pwd2

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class ShahadatiUserCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_validation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            'first_name','last_name',
            'email',
            # I don't know how you want to implement 
            # Shahadati ids, so this solution assumes that
            # they 'Auto-Increment' like usual ids.
            # If they don't, simply uncomment the below line:
            # 'shahadati_nID'
        ]

    def clean_password_validation(self):
        pwd1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        pwd2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_validation')
        if pwd1 and pwd2 and pwd1 != pwd2:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return pwd2

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.set_password(self.cleaned_data.get('password'))
        # comment below 3 lines out if you implement shahadati_nID manually 
        shahadati_num = CustomUser.objects.latest(
            'shahadati_nID'
        ).shahadati_nID + 1
        self.instance.shahadati_nID = shahadati_num
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```py
def normal_user_reg(request):
    form = NormalUserCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'Normal_Register.html', {'form': form})

def shahadati_user_reg(request):
    form = ShahadatiUserCreateForm(
        request.POST or None, 
        request.FILES or None
    )
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'Shahadati_Register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: seems a good solution! but the problem is that the other user who I didn't mention-my fault- have a very different attributes,  They have an address and other things that shahadati user doesn't have, so I cant do the boolean approach, what you suggest?

Comment: Will update the code to show how the solution still works in that situation

Comment: I would like to share a photo of the Users table in the database with you .. but I don't know how.. but the way you mentioned is storage consuming That shahadati users and other users have nothing in common except the email and password... all other attributes are different... so, there is a lot of nulls in the table... I'm sorry I can't suggest your answer.